Tips for learning German precisely just for the purpose of reading the philosophical canon in German?
I hope this question belongs here, as it's not a question about philosophy, but rather a concern with how I may be able to obtain the skills that would help me achieve the specific goal of reading German texts in philosophy. I understand this sounds a bit dumb, but I would like to provide some context:

I'm a graduate student in philosophy, so I've read widely enough to know what areas of philosophy interest me more than others; i.e. this question does not stem from something like "I want to learn German because Kant was German".

In the past, I have been learning German on my own, and at one point I did get to something like a C1 level (this is not a potentially deluded self-report, I had a private teacher when I was really motivated, and this was her assessment). But very predictably, once I became caught up in other things (the actual, concrete tasks in my studies), I just stopped practicing altogether and I have retained next to nothing of what I was capable of. Also this exact pattern has happened many times in the past ~10 years for me in the topic of learning German alone.

Now that I have changed my academic environment (I used to be based in the UK), I'm seeing the importance of learning German even more, for myself, personally. Purely because a strikingly high percentage of the philosophy that really interests me was originally written in German (I was always aware of this, but I feel the motivation even more now because here, in Hungary to be specific, a lot of the people doing philosophy actually do know the language of the philosopher(s) they are working with), and recently I'm starting to think it may even be a path I would like to take.

The fundamental problem is this: I want to learn German, really just for the purpose of reading German philosophers (whether this is the German Idealists, or more modern philosophy such as hermeneutics, phenomenology), and I am not at all interested in modern German society, or even in conversing with Germans in particular. As in, I am wondering if it is possible to somehow approach German in the way that people approach Latin, Ancient Greek etc, i.e. for purely exegetical purposes. And clearly this would be difficult because then I would be dealing with something that is dead (at least in terms of my specific goal). I'm just wondering if anyone has done it this way.

I don't know if this is relevant, but just to eliminate any possibility of false assumptions, I'm not monolingual and English isn't my first language. I was born and raised elsewhere and I speak three other languages fluently.


Thank you so much if you've read this far, any advice or suggestions would be highly appreciated!

@JoWehler Thank you for your answer. Perhaps I should clarify some points in my post: (i) it is very possible I would be pursuing this not merely in a leisurely fashion, since I am determined (for now) to go into academia, and surely if I wanted to specialise in those philosophies/ schools, it makes more sense to know the language; and (ii) in terms of the difficulty of language acquisition itself, I’m actually not so worried, as I suggested in the post. So I’m wondering if there is an efficient way to do this, for the particular purpose I described, hoping someone has had similar experiences.

You might better off posting at German SE. Meiner Meinung nach hab Sie eine gute Frage gefragt. Manchmal kaufe ich Bücher mit beide Sprachen. Zum Beispiel: Philosophical Investigations und finde jemanden, mit dem du üben kannst. (That's what I do as an native English speaker.)

@JD Vielen Dank für Ihren hilfreichen Vorschlag. Sie haben ebenfalls Recht, dass meine Frage wahrscheinlich in diesem anderen Stack-Exchange Bereich gehört – es tut mir leid, ich bin neu hier!

Good question, I would ask it here https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/?newreg=fb2d52432bdf4f09b4a445de5920a350

I’m voting to close this question because language-learning strategies are better covered by the sites offered above.

Added my vote to the close votes - for same reason as @JD.

Short answer: Watch as much German tv and as many German movies as possible. Exposure/immersion is the only way to learn a new language as fast as possible. Philosophical texts are generally much easier to read than literature. Their difficulty is not in the language as such. So, combine watching tv with just diving in, reading whomever you like best, and building up a specialized vocabulary. But give yourself a few years ...
Russell once wrote

Language is shot through with the faded hues of past philosophical theories.

but language also infuses concepts with its forgotten metaphors, which may differ subtly in connotation even among Western languages. Take for instance the words "Begriff" or "Auffassung" - those words are less "sterile" than the English words "concept" and "opinion". They suggest "greifen" ("grasp) and "fassen" (hold in your hand), a kind of concrete determinateness. Similar, Heidegger's "Vorhanden-sein" which sounds very "natural" in German, but a bit akward in English translation ("what is at hand"? the "given"? - but "given" has again a different connotation and is too bland). -- I do believe that learning the language can make your grap stronger and perhaps make you see connections that you might otherwise have missed.

I think this sound advice because I do this in English by using etymonline.com and examining a proposed etymology. Often terms become even more concrete when we pull apart morphemes or see the PIE root.

+1 For the examples. I am not a native German speaker, but it seems a particularly well-suited language for philosophy. Other words: Geborgenheit, a beatiful word, but almost untranslatable. Another Heideggerian word, Geworfenheit (thrownnes??) and of course Übermensch, a word best left untranslated, though it probably leaves a lot of people looking for the umlaut on their keyboards...

It's probably quite interesting to read philosophical texts in their original language as every translation is also an interpretation and each language has it's own set of pictures and concepts in which things are phrased. So the relation of words and ideas can change with languages.
Some examples might be that words that for example have the same or similar word stems in German, might have completely different translations in the English language, so a similarity that is apparent in German might be invisible in English (unless specifically hinted at or bridged by using these words as technical terms or whatnot).
Another thing might be the feature of the German language to organically form new words by merging existing words. So what appears to be a technical term could actually tell it's own story just by separating a word into it's constituents and looking at them in isolation and their interplay. So this etymology or pseudo-etymology or plays on words and connections, might get lost in translations.
Also from what I've heard for example Kant is infamous for his endless sentences (Bandwurmsätze), where clauses are nested to create really monstrous sentences where you might have forgotten the start by the time you reach the end of a clause, so stuff like that might need some training if you'd be coming from a language that is accustomed to shorter sentences.
According to this blog Kant's longest sentence stands at 438 words (if you allow for semicolons) or 238 (if only commas are allowed).
Now with regards to technical terms, philosophical works, usually attempt to define their terminology, though having a strong grasp of how these words are used outside of that definition and why they therefore might have chosen this particular definition might help considerably.
So you probably won't get around actually learning the language, with it's grammar and culture, maybe supplementing it with some literature from the time to get an idea of the often old-timey style that is comprehensible but often a little different from modern German and a general feel for what was on people's mind what analogies and metaphors were used and still are used and so on.
You likely won't have to be perfectly accurate on orthography as many especially the older thinkers wrote their works before that was standardized anyway (which also means knowing how a word looks and sounds like might be important to identify it even if it looks slightly different). But idk if for example here "dass meine Frage wahrscheinlich in diesem anderen Stack-Exchange Bereich gehört" the Dativ is used where it should be the Akkusativ that might in the worst case lead to confusion as to who is doing something to what and whatnot.
Viel Erfolg!
